# Convert .jar to .app

Tags: java, macos, deployment, app-bundle

Trying to use App Bundler to convert my .JAR to .APP but the documentation is difficult to understand.

Does anybody know any tutorials or how to do it?

Comment: What specific features does an application bundle provide that is of interest to this app.?  I'll warrant you can get those features (and more) from [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: I want it to be a .app file so it's as native as possible. Also to submit to appstore it needs to be .app.

Comment: *"..to submit to appstore it needs to be .app."*  Ah.  Got the need now.  Thanks for clarifying.  And no, JWS *cannot* do that.

Comment: I figured out how to use appbundler now, although to submit to appstore you need to include JRE, making the file about 150 mb :(

Answer (score -1):

**3 steps answer working definately**

1.In mac download and install netbeans: https://netbeans.org/downloads/  for mac

2.Import your existing project in netbeans environment in mac.

3.Right click on  imported project --> Package as----> select dmg

**It will crate dmg container with .app file and application shortcut**.